# Setting up a dual-boot system from USB? (10.04.3 LTS)

Tags: 10.04, partitioning, dual-boot, installation, live-usb

I'm trying to setup a dual-boot configuration on my computer, and from what I understand the Ubuntu installer has the capacity to downsize Windows' partitions to make way for it's own using an option called "Install side-by-side." I'd intended to use this option, but found in conspicuously absent from the installer from the Live OS. I'm booting Ubuntu off of a USB stick, by the way. Any suggestions as to what's wrong? Also, should I maybe just research how to properly specify the partitions manually and do it that way?

Thanks for reading!

-Redd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the advanced partition editor option in the installer?
[image]